# how to target all links in footer element

Tags: css

I have a website that I am trying to upgrade from HTML4 to HTML5.

The previous code is:

```
<div id="footer">some text and stuff ...
    <a href="http://">something1</a> | 
    <a href="http://">something 2</a> | 
    <a href="http://">something 3</a>
</div>
```

Some of the CSS going with this is:

```
#footer a {
    color: #CCC;
}
```

Now I thought I just change the `<div>` tag to  and fix up the CSS, but I don't get it to work.

Here's how I thought it would work.

```
<footer>some text and stuff ...
    <a href="http://">something1</a> | 
    <a href="http://">something 2</a> | 
    <a href="http://">something 3</a>
</footer>

footer a {
    color: #CCC;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**** edit: okay, this handled the problem: (I guess the style was overridden through some other rule somewhere :/ )

```
<footer>some text and stuff ...
    <a href="http://">something1</a> | 
    <a href="http://">something 2</a> | 
    <a href="http://">something 3</a>
</footer>

footer a {
    color: #CCC important!;
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on IE8 or lower version?
this works. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7xwuhgqo/

Comment: I was working in Dreamweaver 5.5 on that. Since CS 5, Dreamweaver is supposed to support HTML5 so I didn't expect it not to work properly. Maybe it's a bug in DW then... I will check in some browsers.

Comment: default style tag `<a>` => `a:-webkit-any-link {
color: -webkit-link;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: auto;
}`

Comment: Don't use `important` if you don't have to. Things can and will get ugly down the road. Use specificity or the cascade to overwrite a previous style, not the important declaration.

Comment: @hungerstar that's why we need to petition the W3C to create a `!very-important` in the next CSS release /s

Comment: @88MPG um, no. For the time being I'm going to assume you are joking.

Comment: hence the "/s" for sarcasm. 100% not serious.

Comment: Ah, lol. I did not notice that "/s".